# Como borrar un Nodo específico- Java

Tags: java, xml

Estoy realizando un proyecto en el que es necesario borrar el nodo en el que coincida el nombre que contiene al nombre que selecciona el usuario en un listView que se le pasa al método de eliminar como parámetro (dato).
Ejemplo a lo que me refiero:
El usuario escoge Pepe, yo quiero borra el nodo que contenga el nombre Pepe. 
Este es el código del método en cuestión:

```
private void eliminar(String dato) {
        try {
        String xmlfile = "partners.xml";
       // File file = new File(this.getExternalFilesDir(null), xmlfile);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(new File(xmlfile));

            // 2. buscar y eliminar el elemento <Nombre> que contenga la cadena de carácteres iguales al del parámetro dato de entre
            //    muchos elementos <Nombre> ubicados en cualquier posicion del documento
            NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName("Nombre");
            for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {
                Element element = (Element) items.item(i);
                // elejir un elemento especifico 
                if (items.item(0).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase(dato)) {
                    // borrar elemento
                    element.getParentNode().removeChild(element);
                }
            }
        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Y esta es la estructura del xml:

```
<Empresa>
  <Partners>
     <Partner>
        <Nombre>beñat</Nombre>
        <Direccion>calle a</Direccion>
        <Telefono>666126121</Telefono>
        <Email>rodrigo</Email>
     </Partner>
   </Partners>
</Empresa>
```

El problema es que por alguna razón no me borra nodo y tampoco me da error. Gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Comment: Si lo que te refieres es a borrarlo del xml es normal que no te funcione pues solo lo estas borrando de la estructura que esta en memoria. Necesitarias regrabar el fichero una vez eliminado de memoria.

Comment: Mejor extraes lo que necesitas y creas uno nuevo como reemplazo.